# How can I get a hide/unhide button to also sends post request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code that allows a field to be edited via a input thats hidden/shown when a button is clicked.  It works fine but it only locally changes the data on the page(no updates to my database. Which means when a user edits their profile its saved on the database).  I know how to submit a form without a refresh using jquery but I don't understand how to combine the two so someone can edit a field(in place) and then when they click done it submits it without a refresh(like facebook).

The issue is using the code below the 'edit' button(which is just a anchor) turns into 'save' button then back into 'edit'.  I thought for me to submit the field, I need the button to be a  submit button?

Here's the code I'm using to do the in place editing:

```
$('#editvalue').click(function(e){$('#storedvalue').hide();$('#altervalue').show();});
$('#savevalue').click(function(e){
   var showNew = $('#changevalue').val();
   $('#altervalue').hide();
   $('#storedvalue').show();
   $('#storedvalue span').text(showNew);
});
```

And I learned how to submit a form without a refresh from here a [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/).  I'm not sure how to combine them for the effect I want but I'm not sure if this is even the right way to approach the problem.  Is there a way take the `showNew` variable and submit it as a post without the user clicking a submit button(maybe triggered when the user clicks save)?

I'm super new to jquery and web programming so sorry if I'm not explaining this right.  If it helps here's the html that works with the js code above:
PHP jQuery Example:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="container">
      <div id="storedvalue"><span>Hello</span> [<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="editvalue">edit</a>]</div>
      <div id="altervalue" style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="changevalue" id="changevalue" value="Hello"> [<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="savevalue">save</a>]</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your question. Am I correct if I assume that you normal text that switches to an input field on a button press (i.e inplace-editing), then posts the new value via AJAX (no page refresh) to the server, and then updates the inplace text?

Comment: @RasmusFranke yes that's what I'm trying to do.  I want a user to be able to update their profile fields by clicking on a edit button beside each field.  Once they click on the edit button a text input and save button appears that allows them to modify the field and when they hit save it updates the page and sends a post request so I can update the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, simply do an AJAX post as described at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ inside your $('#savevalue').click(function(e){...})` function. something like this:

```
$('#editvalue').click(function(e){$('#storedvalue').hide();$('#altervalue').show();});
$('#savevalue').click(function(e){
    var showNew = $('#changevalue').val();
    $('#altervalue').hide();
    $.post("test.php", { val: showNew } );
    $('#storedvalue').show();
    $('#storedvalue span').text(showNew);
});
```

This would post the single field to the test.php page. You can (and should) add success/failure callbacks aswell to see if everything went as expected.

Of course, this value will have to be handled on the PHP side for the rest.

EDIT: example with more generic code, including html generation at http://jsfiddle.net/X8Rsg/4/

Comment: wow thanks. I'll play around with this and see how it goes. it looks like what I want though(but alot simpler than what I was trying to do).

Comment: Also, instead of coding this manually, you could use a JQuery plugin that automatically handles the show/hide parts and also submits to the server automatically. Check out http://code.google.com/p/jquery-in-place-editor/ for example. A one-liner could basicly solve the whole javascript part.

Comment: Thanks, I saw something similar in another library but I wanted to learn how to do it myself then I'll explore other libraries.  Your solution worked perfectly, I can't believe I can post so easily(I thought I needed a submit button).  I had a another question, say my page has 20 items to edit do I need to make this above code for each section or is there a way to identify the form they are filling? Right now, I'm posting val: "Rasmus", but can I get info on the field so it sends first_name: "Rasmus" and last_name: "Franke" without making 20 copies? or would it cause problems with validation?

Comment: Made a short example, check it out at http://jsfiddle.net/X8Rsg/4/ . The code causes all containers with the class "inplace-editor" to generate some small amount of html to solve the inplace editing task, you can add any number of fields without changing the code.

Comment: Hey Rasmus! Sorry I've been not coding for the last few days..I just tried your example and its friggin amazing! Thanks so much..my template has alot less code now and alot easier to read!